# Programatically create new NUnit Test based on Configuration File

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm looking to find out if it's possible to dynamically add additional tests to NUnit at runtime, which I plan to base on a configuration file. My testing is designed to compare data from two sources (such as a dev system and a test system, for a particular set of values, including date and client.) Due to this, data doesn't need to be hardcoded (which I do for other test.) I have currently set up a whole lot of tests for a select set of values that I want to test (for example, different dates and clients) which are hard coded into my source code, similar to as follows:

```
[Test]
public void ClientName_Janurary_1_2012()
{
    RunTest("Client Name", new DateTime(2012, 1, 1));
}
```

However, that means that should additional dates need to be tested, the source code needs to be altered to add a `[Test]` method for each of those dates (and normally those test methods will only be one line, which is calling another method with the date as a parameter.)

Is it possible to dynamically create tests that appear in NUnit at runtime, so tests can be added by altering a configuration file?

Comment: (Off-topic remark about terminology: I dare say that these are not unit tests, even though NUnit is used.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, what you're really asking (I think) is how to use new test *data* at runtime.

You can do this natively in NUnit using the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute.  Just point the attribute to a function that reads your configuration file and maps inputs to the desired outputs.  Each point in the test data will show up as a separate "child" of that test method.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Just out of curiosity, is this method able to create tree structures? That said, tree structures are simply a nice to have, and TestCaseSource was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @joshhendo, I don't think you can create nested test cases in NUnit 2.5, but, full disclosure, I've never actually used TestCaseSource myself :)  I'd read about it before, and ended up using ValueSource, which works similarly (for inputs only).

Comment: That's fine, being able to specify the test name (and as such be able to have it in alphabetical order) works, and it works exactly the way I was hoping it would!

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that instead of generating new tests every time your data changes, you write a single, parameterized test and an NUnit extension that uses the file as input for your test. You can probably use something like [NUnit RowTest](http://code.google.com/p/rowtest-extension/downloads/list) as a starting point.